# Cuantos hilos por nucleo es lo maximo posible en Java ExecutorService?

Tags: java, hilos, multitasking

Tengo alrededor de 160.000 iteraciones, cada iteracion debe entrar en un hilo. La pregunta es cual es la mayor cantidad de hilos que soportaria mi cpu y que no se caiga la ejecucion del programa con algun Exception de memoria.
Pongamos un ejemplo con el cpu de mi laptop:

[image: procesador]

16GB de RAM

Actualmente estoy usando esta instruccion:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1000);
```

Tambien investigando alguno sugiere que obtenga la cantidad de hilos con:

```
int hilos = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
```

pero esto retorna solo 16, y me parece que es muy poco, pienso que cada core debe procesar mas hilos que solo 16 o estoy equivocado.

Comment: No es lo mismo procesadores que hilos; hay procesadores físicos y lógicos, considera que [*hyperthreading*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-Threading) permite ejecutar mas de un hilo en cada núcleo.

Comment: Así lo entiendo yo: Tu procesador tiene 16 hilos que puede manejar en simultaneo. Evidentemente no son todos para tu aplicación, ya que el PC hace muchas otras mientras esta en uso. En tu aplicación puedes crear muchos hilos, que van entrando al procesador según la prioridad y el *round robin*. Tus hilos en JAVA consumirán memoria RAM mientras están en cola, la cantidad de memoria disponible depende de la configuración de la JVM que de manera predeterminada crea un valor máximo teniendo en cuanta tu RAM disponible y tu procesador.

Comment: Por tanto, al no saber cuanta RAM tienes y no saber cuanta RAM consume cada hilo de tu APP, es imposible responder cual sería el valor que gatilla una Exception de Memoria (que supongo te refieres a `OutOfMemoryError` )

Comment: Ya edite la publicación, es 16 Gb de Ram.

Comment: La mejora de rendimiento es más notoria cuando dedicas hilos a diferentes trabajos pesados. Tampoco tiene sentido dividir la carga de un mismo trabajo a más hilos que la cantidad de hilos físicos del procesador.